# Transformation of the NDSolve result into new dependent variables

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I have solved a set of coupled differential equations and now I need to convert them into  different dependent variables and sketch their trajectories.

Here is the code I have written so far:

```
zeta1 = x[t] + I y[t];
Eqn1 = (I/zeta1 + 1/Im[zeta1])/(8 Pi Conjugate[zeta1]);
s = NDSolve[{x'[t] == Re[Eqn1], y'[t] == -Im[Eqn1], x[0] == 1, 
y[0] == 1}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 10}];
```

The new coordinates are obtained as follows:

```
p[t] = -x[t]^2 + y[t]^2

q[t] = -2 x[t] y[t]
```

Any ideas how should I do this ?

Comment: Look up `Table` and `Map`.

Answer (score 1):

```
zeta1 = x[t] + I y[t];
eqn1 = (I/zeta1 + 1/Im[zeta1])/(8 Pi Conjugate[zeta1]);
s = NDSolve[{x'[t] == Re[eqn1], y'[t] == -Im[eqn1],x[0] == y[0] == 1}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 10}]; 
Grid[{Plot[# /. s,           {t, 0, 10}, Evaluated -> True, PlotLabel -> ##], 
      ParametricPlot[# /. s, {t, 0, 10}, Evaluated -> True, PlotLabel -> ##]} & /@ 
                                    {{x[t], y[t]}, {-x[t]^2 + y[t]^2, -2 x[t] y[t]}}, Frame -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]